# OData SingleResult with valid, not 404 Null Value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a model:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Buzz Buzz { get; set; }
}

public class Buzz
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And I would like to make OData requests like:

`/odata/Foos`
`/odata/Foos(1)`
`/odata/Foos(2)/Bar`
`/odata/Foos(2)/Bar?$expand=Buzz`

For `/odata/Foos({ID})/Bar` request it's natural to return null (NoContent/204) not 404 in case of property is null. But I am struggling to implement this in an efficient way.

My current solution is:

```
    [EnableQuery]
    public IActionResult GetBar(int key)
    {
        var barQuery = storage.AsQueryable()
            .Where(p => p.Id == key)
            .Select(p => p.Bar);

        if (!barQuery.Any()) // Ok to return null if even Foo not exists
        {
            return NoContent();
        }

        return Ok(SingleResult.Create(barQuery));
    }
```

Problem with it - we have to hit database twice - Check for `Any()` and then During Query Enumeration in result.

Is it possible to make this with a single database request?
Idea is to implement something like `ValidNullableSingleResult`, that not produce 404 for null like `SingleResult`

Note:
We have possible queries like `/odata/Foos(2)/Bar?$expand=Buzz`, this means that we have to deal with IQueryable and can't just use `SingleOrDefault()` and then return the result.

Comment: @Lightman it will be almost the same as with Any() - extra database request. I'm trying to achieve with just one request in all cases.

Comment: Hi, @Vladimir, Entity Framework Plus - [Query Future](https://entityframework-plus.net/query-future) and [Query Deferred](https://entityframework-plus.net/query-deferred) will help u to excute queries in one SQL.